# Match a word just once - AWK

Tags: regex, awk

I was reading GNU awk manual but I didnt find a  regular expression wich whom I can match a string just once.
For example from the files aha_1.txt, aha_2.txt, aha_3.txt, .... I would like to print the second column $2 from the first time ana appears in the files (aha_1.txt, aha_2.txt, aha_3.txt, ....). In addition, the same thing when pedro appears.

**aha_1.txt**

luis 321 487

ana 454 345

pedro 341 435

ana 941 345

**aha_2.txt**

pedro 201 723

gusi 837 134

ana  319 518

cindy 738 278

ana 984 265

.

.

.

.

Meanwhile I did this but it counts all the cases not just the first time

/^ana/ {print  $2 } 
/^pedro/ {print  $2 }

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: If line 2 was `banana 454 345` instead of `ana 454 345`, what would your expected output be?

Answer (score 3):

Just call the exit command after printing the first value(*second column in the line which starts with the string `ana`*).

```
$ awk '$1~/^ana$/{print $2; exit}' file
454
```

Comment: Why not just `$1=="ana"`

Comment: Yes, but one uses regex and its not needed for an exact match. Its also simpler to read. But yes, both works fine.

Answer (score 1):

#### Original question

Only processing one file.

```
awk '/ana/ { if (ana++ == 0) print $2 }' aha.txt
```

or

```
awk '/ana/ && ana++ == 0 { print $2 }' aha.txt
```

Or, if you don't need to do anything else, you can exit after printing, as suggested by [Avinash Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/avinash-raj) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25757221/15168).

#### Revised question

> I have many files (`aha.txt`, `aha_1.txt`, `aha_2.txt`, ...) each file has `ana` inside and I need just to take the fist time `ana` appears in each file and the output has to be one file.

That's sightly different as a question.  If you have GNU `grep`, you can use (more or less):

```
grep -m1 -e ana aha*.txt
```

That will list the whole line, not just column 2, and will list the filenames too, so it isn't a perfect match.

Using `awk`, you have to work a bit more:

```
awk 'FILENAME != old_file { ana = 0; old_file = FILENAME }
     /ana/ { if (ana++ == 0) print $2 }' aha*.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is that I have many files (aha.txt, aha_1.txt, aha_2.txt, ...) each file has ana inside and I need just to take the fist time ana appears in each file and the output have to be one file.

Comment: That's a different question, of course -- it is so much easier to give the right answer when you ask the right question.  It's not very different, but it is different.